# UICollectionView Flow layout no fixed row height

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How to modify the flow layout, so that there is the same vertical spacing between the smaller and larger cells (eg. there is no fixed row height / the row height is not fixed to the maximal size)?

[image]

I want to look it like this

[image]

Comment: The same vertical spacing aligned to top or to bottom?. As they are different sizes is impossible to fit both conditions at the same time.

Comment: to have same vertical spacing between cells, and same vertical spacing from the top

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using [UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout)

Follow the setup from the website, and you can setup it like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout * layout = (UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.delegate = self;
    layout.columnCount = 2;
    layout.itemWidth = 150.f;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    ...
}
```